Operator norm with respect to the l-2 norm of the matrix that have identical elements
I am interested in a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, m\geq n$, whose elements are identically $a$. Is there a way to relate $||A||$, the operator norm of the matrix induced by vector 2-norm, to the identical element's value, $a$?
I understand that the $||A||=\sigma_{max}(A)$ and having all elements identical means that $rank(A)=1$ so there is only 1 non-zero singular value which will be $||A||$ itself. But I do not understand how to relate the individual element's value to the singular value.
I am also trying to understand the problem geometrically as $||A||=\sigma_{max}(A)$ corresponds to the "maximum blow-up factor" of the matrix operating on a vector $x$ with $||x||=1$. I feel like I am close but still cannot get to the end.

Do you mean the Frobenius norm or the operator norm with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm? What have you tried?

Hi @QiaochuYuan, I am interested in the operator norm induced by the vector 2-norm. I updated my question with the description and my understanding. Thank you!

Hint: $A = a uv^T$, where $u, \ v$ are vectors of all ones. Can you compute the singular value decomposition of this matrix?

Thank you, @whpowell96! I think I found the solution and posted it as the answer.

Thanks to @whpowell96 's hint, I found the answer.
$A$ can be written as $A=auv^T$, where $u \in \mathbb{R}^m, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u,v$ are vectors of all ones. To obtain the SVD, $u$ and $v$ has to be normalized: $\hat{u}=\frac{u}{||u||}, \hat{v}=\frac{v}{||v||}$, where $||u||=\sqrt{m}, ||v||=\sqrt{n}$.
It becomes $A = a\sqrt{m} \sqrt{n} \hat{u} \hat{v}^T$, which is the SVD of $A$ with only one non-zero singular value $a \sqrt{m} \sqrt{n}$ and it's the operator norm with respect to $\ell^2$ norm of $A$.
In conclusion:
$$||A||=a\sqrt{m} \sqrt{n}$$
